# Fixing QGIS Expression

Tags: qgis, qgis-expression

I want to say if "field1" is (this or this or this) And "field2" is (this or this or this) then Z.

What is wrong with my expression?

(There are more lines after the first, but I excluded them because they follow the same scheme). I tried replacing When with IN but that doesn't work either.

```
CASE 
  WHEN "X" =  ('X1', 'X2') AND "Y" =  ('Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'Y4') THEN Z
END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator:

> The IN operator is a shorthand for multiple OR conditions.

```
CASE

WHEN "X" IN('X1', 'X2') AND "Y" IN('Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'Y4') THEN Z

END
```